# How to include time dependent variables into ode-solver in Scilab?

Tags: parameters, ode, scilab

I am currently solving a system of nonlinear ODE's. It is a set of kinematic motion equations, where I need to calculate the position angles with given anguar velocities

I found out, how to add a function dependent on time using the list, but the question is, how to add a parameter which is also time dependent, but given as a vector.

Simplified is it written in the following code. c(t) is a time function.

```
function dx = f(t, x, c)

dx(1) = x(1)*sin(x(2))
dx(2) = c*x(2)*cos(x(1))
dx(3) = t*cos(x(3))
endfunction

c = 1:32; // values from measured signal, here simplyfied

y0 = [0.1;0.1;0.1];

t0 = 0;

t = 0:0.1:%pi;

y = ode(y0, t0, t, list (f, c));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See

- https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/interp1.html and
- https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/interpln.html

on how to convert a function table into an interpolating function.

---

#### using `interpln` linear interpolation

Essentially, in the right side function `dx=f(t,x,tc_arr)` you evaluate

```
function dx=f(t,x,tc_arr)
  c = interpln(tc_arr, t)
  dx(1) = x(1)*sin(x(2))
  dx(2) = c*x(2)*cos(x(1))
  dx(3) = t*cos(x(3))
endfunction
```

where `tcarr` contains arrays of sampling times and sampling values.

---

#### an example signal for tests

As an example signal, take

```
t_sam = -1:0.5:4;
c_sam = sin(2*t_sam+1);

tc_arr = [ t_sam; c_sam ];
```

Note that you always will need the sample times to find out how the input time `t` relates to the value array.

```
t = 1.23;
c = interpln(tc_arr, t)
```

returns `c = - 0.2719243`.

---

#### using `interp1` 1D interpolation (with splines)

You could as well use the other function, which has more options in terms of interpolation method.

```
function dx=f(t,x,t_sam,c_sam)
  c = interp1(t_sam, c_sam, t, "spline", "extrap")
  dx(1) = x(1)*sin(x(2))
  dx(2) = c*x(2)*cos(x(1))
  dx(3) = t*cos(x(3))
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But unfortunantelly it does not work, there are two points I dont understand.
1/ When defining the function _f_, shouldnt you write rather `dx=f(t, x, c)`? If I defined the funtion with the original array tc_arr, then I do not understand, why I do I have to call the interpolation, if I do not use its product anyway.
2/ Product of the function _interp1_ is a vector. If I run the code, I get error reported: _Submatrix incorrectly defined.
ode: An error occurred in 'lsoda' subroutine._. The same as before.

Comment: Yes, that was wrong. I mixed the call interfaces of the two cited functions, now the correct function for that parameter setup is used.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general solution than that of LutzL, you just need to define `c(t)` and call it from inside de ODE:

```
function v = c(t)
    //definition of c(t)
    v = ...
endfunction

function dx = f(t, x, c)
    dx(1) = x(1)*sin(x(2))
    dx(2) = c(t)*x(2)*cos(x(1))
    dx(3) = t*cos(x(3))
endfunction
```

Comment: That would be the best way, but...unfortunantelly I did not mention, that c(t) is actually a measured signal. I have the values in a form of a vector, so I just creaed here another vector, to simplify it. Therefore I can not define it with a function. Sorry for confusig you.

Answer (score 0):

Putting all ideas together gives this working script :

```
function v = c(tc_arr,t)
    //definition of c(t)
    v = interpln(tc_arr,t)
endfunction

function dx = f(t, x, c, tc_arr)
    dx(1) = x(1)*sin(x(2))
    dx(2) = c(tc_arr, t)*x(2)*cos(x(1))
    dx(3) = t*cos(x(3))
endfunction

// measured signal (e.g. 10 samples here)
t_sam = linspace(0, %pi, 10)
c_sam = sin(2*t_sam+1)
tc_arr = [t_sam; c_sam]

y0 = [0.1;0.1;0.1];
t0 = 0;
t = 0:0.1:%pi;

y = ode(y0, t0, t, list(f, c, tc_arr));

plot(t,y)
```

As explained previously, using interpolation (linear here) allows to compute `c(t)` values at arbitrary values of `t`, which are needed by the ode solver.

Comment: Can you test the following script and validate the answer ?