# Solving vector second order differential equation while indexing into an array

Tags: python-3.x, ode

I'm attempting to solve the differential equation:

m(t) = M(***x***)***x''*** + C(***x***, ***x'***) + B ***x'***

where ***x*** and ***x'*** are vectors with 2 entries representing the angles and angular velocity in a dynamical system. M(***x***) is a 2x2 matrix that is a function of the components of theta, C is a 2x1 vector that is a function of theta and theta' and B is a 2x2 matrix of constants. m(t) is a 2*1001 array containing the torques applied to each of the two joints at the 1001 time steps and I would like to calculate the evolution of the angles as a function of those 1001 time steps.

I've transformed it to standard form such that :

***x''*** = M(***x***)^-1 (m(t) - C(***x***, ***x'***) - B ***x'***)

Then substituting ***y_1*** = ***x*** and ***y_2*** = ***x'*** gives the first order linear system of equations:

***y_2*** = ***y_1'***

***y_2'*** = M(***y_1***)^-1 (m(t) - C(***y_1***, ***y_2***) - B ***y_2***)

(I've used theta and phi in my code for x and y)

```
def joint_angles(theta_array, t, torques, B):

    phi_1 = np.array([theta_array[0], theta_array[1]])
    phi_2 = np.array([theta_array[2], theta_array[3]])

    def M_func(phi):
        M = np.array([[a_1+2.*a_2*np.cos(phi[1]), a_3+a_2*np.cos(phi[1])],[a_3+a_2*np.cos(phi[1]), a_3]])
        return np.linalg.inv(M)

    def C_func(phi, phi_dot):
        return a_2 * np.sin(phi[1]) * np.array([-phi_dot[1] * (2. * phi_dot[0] + phi_dot[1]), phi_dot[0]**2])

    dphi_2dt = M_func(phi_1) @ (torques[:, t] - C_func(phi_1, phi_2) - B @ phi_2)

    return dphi_2dt, phi_2

t = np.linspace(0,1,1001)
initial = theta_init[0], theta_init[1], dtheta_init[0], dtheta_init[1]

x = odeint(joint_angles, initial, t, args = (torque_array, B))
```

I get the error that I cannot index into torques using the t array,  which makes perfect sense, however I am not sure how to have it use the current value of the torques at each time step.

I also tried putting odeint command in a for loop and only evaluating it at one time step at a time, using the solution of the function as the initial conditions for the next loop, however the function simply returned the initial conditions, meaning every loop was identical. This leads me to suspect I've made a mistake in my implementation of the standard form but I can't work out what it is. It would be preferable however to not have to call the odeint solver in a for loop every time, and rather do it all as one.

If helpful, my initial conditions and constant values are:

```
    theta_init = np.array([10*np.pi/180, 143.54*np.pi/180])
    dtheta_init = np.array([0, 0])

    L_1 = 0.3
    L_2 = 0.33
    I_1 = 0.025
    I_2 = 0.045
    M_1 = 1.4
    M_2 = 1.0
    D_2 = 0.16

    a_1 = I_1+I_2+M_2*(L_1**2)
    a_2 = M_2*L_1*D_2
    a_3 = I_2
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: This scilab answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/57392624/3088138 is equally valid in python. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why I would need the interpolation function - the times I want to solve the equation for are the exact same times that the torques have been evaluated at. All I need is to use the first column of 'torques' for the first evaluation of the ODE, then the second, etc. I'm sure it's trivial but I don't know how to index into 'torques' in the context of the ode solver - without indexing I get the error message: 'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,1001) (2,)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solver uses an internal stepping that is problem adapted. The given time list is a list of points where the internal solution gets interpolated for output samples. The internal and external time lists are in no way related, the internal list only depends on the given tolerances.

---

There is no actual natural relation between array indices and sample times.

> The translation of a given time into an index and construction of a sample value from the surrounding table entries is called *interpolation* (by a piecewise polynomial function).

---

Torque as a physical phenomenon is at least continuous, a piecewise linear interpolation is the easiest way to transform the given function value table into an actual continuous function. Of course one also needs the time array.

So use `numpy.interp1d` or the more advanced routines of `scipy.interpolate` to define the torque function that can be evaluated at arbitrary times as demanded by the solver and its integration method.